# Test Automation with NetSuite

Tags: automated-tests, netsuite

Has anyone tried using an automated test tool (like Chai or Selenium) that can be used to run automated test cases within NetSuite?

For example, I want to create an automated test case that would test if a Client Script was setting the correct values, etc.

TIA

Comment: We do all of our testing in a paid NetSuite sandbox environment.  Are you looking for a lower cost solution or are you looking beyond the capabilities of a NetSuite sandbox?

Answer (score 3):

We build our SuiteApp as an npm package that uses [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) with [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/). As much as possible, we try to isolate our business logic code from any NetSuite APIs, then we automate unit testing on the isolated logic. We use sinon to mock NetSuite APIs where we can't avoid them. We don't worry about testing the actual NetSuite API methods, as if those are broken, there's not a lot we can do to fix them anyway.

We tried Selenium several years ago (2013 maybe) for automated testing in the browser, but it could never seem to record the macros correctly and would always result in broken test suites. Perhaps both Selenium and the NetSuite DOM have improved since then; would certainly be worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

We have created an open source tool for unit testing suite scripts, it allows you to test your scripts outside of netsuite:

https://github.com/3EN-Cloud/netsumo